# mousewheel or e.stopPropagation not working with firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm currently working on the project of mine and i have made a horizontal scrolling website.

what the problem seems to be is that when i have a scrollable div (vertically) in my horizontal webpage i can't scroll it vertically anymore.

this is the website: [ShareApe.com](http://m.shareape.com/)

i have used this working code but it seems that firefox is not working with the option mousewheel or e.stopPropagation();.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fileUpload').on('mousewheel', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
 });
});
</script>
```

i've come by this website http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml
but i can't figure out how to use this fix.

Many thanks for your time!

Patrick Falize

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support .onmousewheel, you have to use the DOMMouseScroll event instead:

```
$(document).on( "mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

oke so i figure it out. firefox has no problems with e.stopPropagation(); but the problem was with the moudewheel function. so i added "DOMMouseScroll" to the .on and it worked like a sharm!